# outputting only TRUE results to users

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

Christian helped me on the below and I have changed it a bit to check the value of the key as well. Anyway, the problem I now have is still based on the output that I provide to the user. I do not want to display the key name but rather the value of the key.

The value of the key is based on what key(s) have been found to be TRUE (in the code below).

So, if the below result has a TRUE against keys 1 (value of key is ONE), 2 (value of key is TWO) and 3 (value of key is THREE) then how do I put a WRITE-HOST to the user based on the specific keys found only?

ie I want the result that is provided to have an output of one of the below when it is all the parameters in a specific case are TRUE.

```
Write-Host "The value of the keys are $keyvalue1"

Write-Host "The value of the keys are $keyvalue1 and $keyvalue2"

Write-Host "The value of the keys are $keyvalue1 and $keyvalue2 and $keyvalue3"

Write-Host "The value of the keys are $keyvalue1 and $keyvalue2 and $keyvalue3 and $keyvalue4"
```

Here is the code:

```
$keyvalue1 = (Get-ItemProperty hklm:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\SNMP\Parameters\TrapConfiguration\$CommunityName -Name 1).'1'
$keyvalue2 = (Get-ItemProperty hklm:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\SNMP\Parameters\TrapConfiguration\$CommunityName -Name 2).'2'
$keyvalue3 = (Get-ItemProperty hklm:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\SNMP\Parameters\TrapConfiguration\$CommunityName -Name 3).'3'
$keyvalue4 = (Get-ItemProperty hklm:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\SNMP\Parameters\TrapConfiguration\$CommunityName -Name 4).'4'

$testpath1 = (Get-ItemProperty hklm:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\SNMP\Parameters\TrapConfiguration\$CommunityName -Name 1).'1' -ne $null 2>$null
$testpath2 = (Get-ItemProperty hklm:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\SNMP\Parameters\TrapConfiguration\$CommunityName -Name 2).'2' -ne $null 2>$null
$testpath3 = (Get-ItemProperty hklm:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\SNMP\Parameters\TrapConfiguration\$CommunityName -Name 3).'3' -ne $null 2>$null
$testpath4 = (Get-ItemProperty hklm:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\SNMP\Parameters\TrapConfiguration\$CommunityName -Name 4).'4' -ne $null 2>$null

 $a = $testpath1, $testpath2 , $testpath3 , $testpath4 # convert your true/false results in an array
$s = "" # empty string
$i = 1 # a simple variable as index
foreach ($b in $a)
 {
   if ($b -ne $true ) 
   { 
     break
   } 

   $s += "$i " # if true add index in string
   $i++
}

"$($s)is/are true" #output the result
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you duplicating the Get-ItemProperty calls?  You already have the value (or lack thereof) stored in $keyvalue.  You should be able to simplify this to something like this:

```
$keyVals = @()
$keyVals += (Get-ItemProperty hklm:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\SNMP\Parameters\TrapConfiguration\$CommunityName -Name 1).1
$keyVals += (Get-ItemProperty hklm:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\SNMP\Parameters\TrapConfiguration\$CommunityName -Name 2).2
$keyVals += (Get-ItemProperty hklm:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\SNMP\Parameters\TrapConfiguration\$CommunityName -Name 3).3
$keyVals += (Get-ItemProperty hklm:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\SNMP\Parameters\TrapConfiguration\$CommunityName -Name 4).4

Write-Host "The value of keys are " -NoNewLine
$first = $true
foreach ($keyVal in $keyVals) {
    if ($keyVal -ne $null) {
        if (!$first) { 
            Write-Host " and " -NoNewLine 
        }
        $first = $false
        Write-Host $keyVal -NoNewLine
    }
}
Write-Host
```

Comment: why am I duplicating it....because I am not as good as you :-) Thanks a lot for that - your code works and I get the expected results. One question - what does the @() do?

Comment: Just ensures that $keyVals is an array - empty to start with.  PowerShell is real easy going and doesn't require that declaration.  However, if the first value you get back is a string then $keyVals is a string and subsequent use of `+=` just concatenates the values to the string.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (not tested):

```
$keyvalue1 = (Get-ItemProperty hklm:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\SNMP\Parameters\TrapConfiguration\$CommunityName -Name 1).'1'
$keyvalue2 = (Get-ItemProperty hklm:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\SNMP\Parameters\TrapConfiguration\$CommunityName -Name 2).'2'
$keyvalue3 = (Get-ItemProperty hklm:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\SNMP\Parameters\TrapConfiguration\$CommunityName -Name 3).'3'
$keyvalue4 = (Get-ItemProperty hklm:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\SNMP\Parameters\TrapConfiguration\$CommunityName -Name 4).'4'
$testpath1 = (Get-ItemProperty hklm:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\SNMP\Parameters\TrapConfiguration\$CommunityName -Name 1).'1' -ne $null 2>$null
$testpath2 = (Get-ItemProperty hklm:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\SNMP\Parameters\TrapConfiguration\$CommunityName -Name 2).'2' -ne $null 2>$null
$testpath3 = (Get-ItemProperty hklm:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\SNMP\Parameters\TrapConfiguration\$CommunityName -Name 3).'3' -ne $null 2>$null
$testpath4 = (Get-ItemProperty hklm:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\SNMP\Parameters\TrapConfiguration\$CommunityName -Name 4).'4' -ne $null 2>$null

 $a = $testpath1, $testpath2 , $testpath3 , $testpath4 # convert your true/false results in an array

$v = $keyvalue1,$keyvalue2,$keyvalue2,$keyvalue4 
$s = "The value of the keys are " # empty string
$i = 1 # a simple variable as index
foreach ($b in $a)
 {
   if ($b -ne $true ) 
   { 
     break
   } 

   $s += "$($v[$i]) " # if true add value of $v[index] in string
   $i++
}

"$s" #output the result
```

Comment: thanks for that - I do not get any output back - all I get is: "The value of the keys are    " - not too sure why as it seems similar to before. Also, I noticed that I am defining variables under $keyname(1-4) - however, if a key does not exist I get an error in powershell saying it cannot find the path of the key. How do I suppress errors in adding variables?

Comment: I can add a $ErrorActionPreference = "silentlycontinue" at the top to stop the error. But, I am still not getting anything back from the output.